# Embed Not functioning properly Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Im trying to set up my own bot for a server: current code i have

```
import discord


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("random"):
        message_sender = message.author
        embededmessage = discord.Embed(title="TitleTest", description=f"{message_sender} Testdescription")
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embededmessage)
        deletingembed = ['TitleTest', "random"]
        for word in deletingembed:
            if message.content.count(word) > 0:
                await message.channel.purge(limit=2)
```

i have 2 of these on one server, of course all variable are named differently. however evrytime i run the code only one of them works, which is the one below the other, the one on the top doesnt function, i get no error messages.

Comment: what do you mean by the one on top doesnt function? Also, instead of using the client event on_message for commands, use client.commands

Comment: what does the one on top and the one on the bottom mean?

Comment: I mean i have 2 identical version of the code shown(it has different variable names). whenever i run the code only the one in the bottom works, so if i type  "random2" it works but when i type "random" it doesnt work, it sends no messages and there is no error either

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
from dhooks import Embed

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("random"):
message_sender = message.author
EmbededMessage = Embed()
embed.add_field(name = 'TitleTest', value = f"{message_sender} Testdescription")
await message.channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: Is dhooks a whole library, i don't think i have it

Comment: u need to download a pip install dhooks